# programming and numerical analysis

Tags: numerical-analysis

I'm taking a numerical analysis class in the fall with a heavily applied/programming bent. I have a so-so programming background (having taken a few classes and worked on Java programming in an internship) but I want to bone up my skills before I start this class. So my question is, *what programming skills are useful for numerical analysis*?

Are data structures, OOP, algorithms very important? Are there any resources you would recommend I go over before class starts?

Comment: In theory, "language" shouldn't be important.  In practice - see if you can find out what language they're using, and see if you need to brush up on that language *before* class starts.  IMHO...

Comment: There is no set language for the course, I'm considering using Java or C++.

Comment: If your choice is between Java or C++ ... choose Java!!!  It will be *so much* easier on your constitution ;) If you're already familiar with Java (even relatively superficially), then you should be good to go for your class.  IMHO...

Comment: I'm mainly interested in C++ because of its use in industry, I have experience with Java but have just started with C++. My idea is that taking this upper-level class in C++ will help me master the language. Is this a bad idea? :(

Answer (score 1):

Algorithms and data structures.  Not so much OOP.  In the numerical analysis course that I took in college, we did a lot of programming of algorithms in python and Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

You would be best to use numpy and/or scipy if you want to do numerical analysis fast prototyping. The python tutorial for python 2.7 or version 3 is about 120 pages long and available from docs.python.org and very easy to pick up in a day. numpy and scipy take some learning.

The gains using OOP can be large but it takes a lot of skilling up. If I was using C++ I'd use Brian H. Flowers book which can give you a quick introduction to applied engineering and the first 5 chapters will give you the ability to write good C++ OOP classes with about 8 hours work including writing test scripts. The problem now is that many OOP packages are in the standard template libraries. Many people end up reinventing the wheel because they don't know what is available. This is why you might be better to just go for Python numpy or scipy or as suggested above, just use Matlab since most things are predefined. Both languages are good for fast prototyping, but if you are wanting to do quite involved things like produce finite element/finite difference meshes, you will need to go to the BLAS libraries of Dongarra.